# iterate through 2 dictionaries, if value occurs in one, count down the int value in other then remove key if count = 0

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have 2 dictionary objects:

```
members = {'member3': ['PCP3'], 'member4': ['PCP1'], 'member11': ['PCP2'], 'member12': ['PCP3']}
providers = {'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 2, 'PCP3': 1, 'PCP4': 3, 'PCP5': 4}
```

I want to iterate through both and each time a value of the "members" dict appears, subtract one from the count of that particular provider.  If the count of a provider reaches zero, remove them from the "providers" dictionary and randomly pick one of the members out of the "member" dictionary.  So in this case either member3 or member12 will be kicked out because there wasnt enough spots.

Result would look like this if member3 won the random toss for example:

```
members = {'member3' : 'PCP3', 'member4': 'PCP1' , 'member11': PCP2}
providers = {'PCP1: 1, 'PCP2' : 1, 'PCP4': 3, 'PCP5' : 4}
```

I have tried starting with this but this problem is beyond my abilities the moment

```
from collections import defaultdict
query_dict=defaultdict(set)
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(members_reduced.items(), PCPs.items()):
    query_dict[k[v]].subtract(k2[v2])
```

This gives error

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I also tried:

```
for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(members_reduced.items(), PCPs.items()):
if members_reduced[v] == PCPs[k2]:
    PCPs[v2] -= 1
```

With error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I have no idea how I would input the random conditional if I got this first part right.  this is a smaller model of a much larger model i need at work

Comment: It will be much simpler to iterate over `members.items()` and then do `if value in providers: providers[value] -= 1` and so forth.

Comment: It would be hard to give hint for your tentative solutions because you use different names in your input and in your tentative solutions, so they would not run without guessing, which prevent others from debugging them or reproducing your observed behavior without unnecessary guesswork. Please consider adapting your question to produce a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mre).

Comment: Im sorry Im Not sure where you are you referring to different names.  The output dictionaries have the same names.  The structure is also the same except that members has been reduced because one member was booted out and the counts of the providers is less

Comment: `PCPs` and `members_reduced` were used in the solutions of yours but not defined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the task is:

````
import random


members = {'member3': ['PCP3'], 'member4': ['PCP1'], 'member11': ['PCP2'], 'member12': ['PCP3']}
providers = {'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 2, 'PCP3': 1, 'PCP4': 3, 'PCP5': 4}


to_remove = []
for member, provider_list in members.items():
    provider = provider_list[0]
    if provider in providers:
        providers[provider] -= 1
        if providers[provider] == 0:
            providers.pop(provider)
            to_remove.append(provider)
for provider in to_remove:
    candidates = [
        member for member, provider_list in members.items()
        if provider == provider_list[0]]
    candidate = random.sample(candidates, 1)[0]
    members.pop(candidate)


print(members)
# {'member4': ['PCP1'], 'member11': ['PCP2'], 'member12': ['PCP3']}
print(providers)
# {'PCP1': 1, 'PCP2': 1, 'PCP4': 3, 'PCP5': 4}```
````

Basically, we solve the problem in two passes:

- in the first pass we modify the counters and, when the counters reach 0, we mark the `member` to remove
- in the second pass we remove the members according to what was marked for removal

Comment: How would I change the variable ```candidate``` to not just be 1, but be whatever is the the difference between the needed count for that provider and what the providers actual number of open slots?

Comment: @BenSmith I would not remove the negative counts from the `dict` and instead of creating a new `to_remove` list, I would loop through the original `dict` and remove as many items as the negative counts indicate. Perhaps you could ask another question if you have troubles implementing this.

Comment: no ```to_remove``` to have a list of providers that need to go to iterate through.  Where Im stuck now is if there are more than one in ```to_remove``` then there are two sets of members, how do I create a list of lists of those sets.  Like, ```[['member3', 'member12'],
['member14', 'member15', 'member16']]```

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. I don't understand what you are after just from the comments above.